# HTML/CSS slight sideways scrollability, how to find source?

Tags: html, css

I have built a website in HTML/CSS, however at some point along building it I have gained a slight sidway scroll to it, in other words the instead of the website perfectly fitting the screen there are thin bars of white each side that can be accessed through scrolling left or right on the screen. I am wondering how I could find out the source of this issue?

http://whynotapp.co.uk/tryitout.html

This occurs on both safari and chrome

Comment: Just by telling us where you website is.

Comment: Knowing what browser you are using would also be helpful.

Comment: Try the Inspector in Firefox. It will show you exactly what element takes up how much space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could happen because of a left/right margin on a 100% width element/div. It could also happen if you have positioned an element somewhere that causes it to go off the screen.

In general, if nothing is missing from the screen that needs to be on the screen, you can just use :

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

which will hide anything that over extends the x access from the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Inspect element in chrome allows you to see a box of the location and size of an element, by selecting it in html. The element causing the problem should be larger than the containing element, which can help you find it.

F12 to enter dev mode or right click your element.